# automatically import values from external source, and use them for calculations

Tags: javascript, html, import, stockquotes

I'd like to have a system in place which automatically imports financial stock values from an external source to my own site, after which I can make an alghoritm with javascript which makes calculations. But I don't know how I can import data from other websites to my own. Can anyone explain me how that works?

Comment: You have to use their API! Basically you send a request to a specific url and by doing so you will receive data.

Comment: Thank you, very clear answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment you have to use their `API`. There are a lot of sites which show their `API` publicly e.g Twitter. 
Simply put send a request to specific `url` and their servers will respond with the data which you can then process how you want it.

Comment: But there is a way to update the values automatically, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. But if I understood you correctly then yes it can be achieved programmatically and it will be fully automated.